# What is the best way to get index of checked listitem?

Tags: dojo

I am trying to get the index of checked listitem in my code but not able to figure out the way. My HTML code is below-

```
         <h2 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/RoundRectCategory">Select Your Range :</h2>
                <ul id="list" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/RoundRectList" data-dojo-props='select:"single"'>
                  <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem" data-dojo-props='checked:true'>Within 1 KM</li>
                  <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem" >Within 3 KM</li>
                  <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem" >Within 5 KM</li>
                </ul>
```

I tried using dojo.query to reach to the checked listitem but it is also not working. Can someone please help me how to achieve this ?

My dojo code-

```
  dojo.query("#list>li:checked").forEach(function(node) { alert("in for loop"); });
```

I tried using below code which is giving me an alert for index 0 which corresponds to the default selected listitem but when I am selecting any other listitem, I am still getting the alert for the default selected listitem. When I checked in Google chrome's developer tool I found that data-dojo-props='checked:true' for the default listitem is not changing to false when I am selecting any other listitem. Is it the correct behaviour of the listitem ?? Ideally it should get change to false and checked property for the new selected listitem should get change to 'true' but this is not happening. Can anyone please explain this behaviour and tell me the best way to get the index of selected listitem ?

```
  dojo.query("#list>li[data-dojo-props='checked:true']").forEach(function(node,index) { alert("in for loop"+ index); });
```

Note- I settled with using dojo radiobuttons in my listitems which worked very well but am still looking to get help on this just to be aware of this functionality.

Answer (score -1):

By using JQuery.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/RoundRectCategory" >Select Your Range :</h2>
                <ul id="list" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/RoundRectList" data-dojo-props='select:"single"'>
                  <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem" data-dojo-props='checked:true'>Within 1 KM</li>
                  <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem"  data-dojo-props='checked:true' >Within 3 KM</li>
                  <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem" >Within 5 KM</li>
                </ul>
  <input type="button" value="get selected items" onclick="GetData()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetData(){
var Value = "";

$("#list li").each(function(index,ele){
if($(ele).attr("data-dojo-props") === "checked:true")
Value += ","+$(ele).html();
});
alert(Value);
 }
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Sameer for the help but I want to implement it in dojo.